# Battlefield 3 graphic problem with GTX 560ti

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

[image]

I'm using GTX 560ti, my resolution is 1920x1080 and graphic is Ultra with no MSAA.
Dose anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Looks like videocard problems. Have you tried updating the drivers?

Comment: @PoweRoy: I first thought it as same, but other games were normal. and also there is another victim according to my googling. someone says it'll reduce if you set your coreclock to nomal, but I didn't overclocked my GPU. and it happened only on GTX 560Ti, maybe.

Comment: check your graphics card temperature. it's more a question for Superuser.com

Comment: I would usually say this is cause by graphics drivers... update to the latest (non beta) drivers out there. I've before expirienced problems with beta drivers, though it has been a while since I've used them.

Comment: We've had such questions flagged for migration to gaming. Anyways the problem's more of a driver or an overheating problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue and there are several threads on GetSatisfaction about this [here](http://getsatisfaction.com/battlefield3/topics/black_geometric_shapes_covering_textures_field_of_view_gaming_experience) and [here](http://getsatisfaction.com/battlefield3/topics/artifacts-1f24dy). Sounds like both DICE and nVidia have bugs. So far the only solution I've seen is to reduce your settings to "High", no AA (deferred or post), ambient occlusioning to SSAO, and no blur. Those might need to go lower depending on a particular situation. It strikes me as a memory bus issue.

It's rather sad considering how prevalent that card is.

Comment: Hey, I found another solution. Disabled *"ANTIALIASING POST"*, and didn't touch anything. It works fine, no glitches & tearing.

Comment: Yeah it seems to be a case of finding a gfx load setting that works for a particular setup. Turning off AA POST worked when I was running 1680x1050, but I needed to down everything to High at 1080p.